# Excel PivotTable - combine data from 2 sheets - incorrect sum showing

Tags: excel, pivot, pivot-table

Friends,

I am puzzled by a "basic" PivotTable issue I am facing, trying to use data of 2 sheets into 1 PivotTable. *

Sheet 1: "`Orders`", containing order lines with foreign key "`Article ID Nr`"
Sheet 2: "`Articles`", containing article data with primary key "`ID Nr`"

Goal: Pivot listing ordered articles per customer, showing per article line:

- the ordered qty
- total value ("total net" field)
- and the avaialble stock

This is the currently incorrect calculation:

[image: PivotTable, with wrong stock calculation]

and these are the settings:
[image: PivotTable settings]

---

I am able to pull in stock data from the "`Articles`" sheet; however, that data is NOT showing the correct stock for that article, but rather the sum of all article's stock, i.e. the total stock.  Each article line should get the "`Nr` in `Stock`" listed.

I have tried this Pivot model in a test workbook/worksheet, with dummy data.
It DID work in that PivotTable.  However, I cannot find the reason why it does not work properly in my main worksheet.

Structure of Sheet 1 - "Orders":

`ID-Nr (of order) / Client ID-Nr / Client Company Name / Article ID Nr / Article Description / Qty / Total Net (i.e. $-value of order line)`

[image: "Orders" sheet]

Structure of Sheet 2 - "Articles":
`ID-Nr (of article) / Description / Nr In Stock`

[image: "Articles" - sheet]

Any help, suggestions are greatly appreciated.

Kind regards,
Koen

Answer (score 0):

Like the warning in the PivotTable Fields List says, you need to set up a relationship between your two tables.

Click that yellow warning, see if it rectifies the problem. Otherwise set one up manually using the Relationships icon from the PivotTable Tools tab.